# Using ui.select for Administrative levels dropdown in Google Earth Engine

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

How can I use `ui.select` for Administrative levels dropdown in Google Earth Engine? I would like to use `ui.select` to first select the state and then select the county.

Here is the GEE code:

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/States")
var Counties = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/Counties")

var countryNames = countries.aggregate_array('NAME')
var countyNames = Counties.aggregate_array('NAME')

var countryNames = countries.aggregate_array('NAME').getInfo()
function countryNames(names) {      return names}

var countyNames = Counties.aggregate_array('NAME').getInfo()
function countyNames(names) {      return names}

var state = {
country: ui.Select({
items: countryNames,
}),

county: ui.Select({
items: countyNames,
})
};

var update = function(NAME) {
var roi = Map.layers().get(0)
[countries.filterMetadata("NAME", "equals", NAME).getValue()]
[counties.filterMetadata("NAME", "equals", NAME).getValue()]

}

state.country.onChange(update);

state.county.onChange(update);

ui.root.insert(0, ui.Panel([state.country, state.county]));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7d0286ea2eaf4de2a1a8915b9c0d71d6

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this is a bit tricky, I assume you want to filter counties by state, so I found a linking property: `STATEFP`

```js
var states = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/States")
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection("TIGER/2016/Counties")

var statesNames = states.aggregate_array('NAME')

var getCounties = function(state) {
  // Given a state get all counties
  var feat = ee.Feature(states.filterMetadata('NAME', 'equals', state).first())
  var statefp = ee.String(feat.get('STATEFP'))
  var filteredCounties = counties.filterMetadata('STATEFP', 'equals', statefp)
  var filteredCountiesNames = filteredCounties.aggregate_array('NAME')
  return ee.List(filteredCountiesNames)
}

// Empty Dropdowns
var statesDD = ui.Select([], 'Loading..')
var countiesDD = ui.Select([], 'Waiting for a state..')

// Load states
statesNames.evaluate(function(states){
  statesDD.items().reset(states)
  statesDD.setPlaceholder('Select a state')
  statesDD.onChange(function(state){
    // once you select a state (onChange) get all counties and fill the dropdown
    countiesDD.setPlaceholder('Loading...')
    var counties = getCounties(state)
    counties.evaluate(function(countiesNames){
      countiesDD.items().reset(countiesNames)
      countiesDD.setPlaceholder('Select a county')
    })
  })
})

ui.root.insert(0, ui.Panel([statesDD, countiesDD]));
```

[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f1643a7ffe0764243f8d750cee7ead27)

Comment: I will learn about USA counties =) https://code.earthengine.google.com/0340e4bd8cc686a566bd65c4263fbd2a